# Right margin lost when minimizing window

Tags: html, css, margin, minimize

I can provide more specific code if necessary but this basic code should demonstrate my issue.  Essentially my page looks great when the window is maximized (min-width + left + right margin).  But when you minimize the window the right margin disappears.

The idea is to have a body that always maintains a specific page margin around the content.  Then to have the content always centered.

Code below.  I've simplified my implementation to highlight my issue.

```
<style>
  .panel{
     min-width: 1020px;
     max-width: 1200px;
     margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
  }
</style>

<body style="margin: 10px 20px 5px 20px;">
    <div class="panel">
    ....my content
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I ended up solving my issue in another way.  Below is the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I ended up using.

```
<style>
    body{
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
      min-width: 1020px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
   .panel{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="panel">
       ....my content
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'display:inline-block;'

http://jsfiddle.net/CunsN/

```
<body style="display:inline-block;margin: 10px 20px 5px 20px;">
  <div class="panel">
  ....my content
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems to be working.  Thanks!  I still need to check a few other things though.

Answer (score 0):

try position fixed and forget about inline style

```
<style>
body{
   position:fixed;
   top 10px;
   right:20px;
   bottom:5px;
   left:20px;
   display:block;
}
  .panel{
     min-width: 1020px;
     max-width: 1200px;
     margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
  }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="panel">
    ....my content
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but setting a fixed position would require me changing some of the positions and styles of the rest of the elements.  Although I will give this a try just to see how it works in production.  Thanks.